# How to search for flights for a route staying within in an alliance?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, airline-alliances

@LemuelGuliver had an IMO great question lurking in https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81493/how-to-get-to-cairo-from-boston -- how can you search for flights staying within an alliance? His question was using his status, well, that's the point of an alliance, your status will be recognized to some extent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kayak offers the option to filter on Alliance:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

[ITA Matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/) can do this using the `/ alliance` limiter, there's `star-alliance`, `skyteam` and `oneworld`. To give an example I used the original question as parameters -- I couldn't find anything direct so I asked for one connection:

[image: alliance search]

This particular one will correctly find flights on British Airways and Qatar.

Answer (score 6):

Google Flights has this as well as the services offered in other answers. It's under 'Airline'; the alliances are available at the top of the list.
[image: Google Flights screenshot with Airline menu highlighted]